# Issue with adding hours to Gregorian Calendar

Tags: grails, groovy, gregorian-calendar

I have a Grails application I created a Gregorian Calendar GMT date. The time of day was `11:00:00 PM GMT`. I added 3 hours to the Gregorian Calendar object and it changed the time of day to `2:00:00 AM` but it did not increment the day of the year. I had to check for the case when I add hours to the calender and if that new time should pass to a new day I had to increment the day of the year. This seems like a bug in the GregorianCalendar class but want to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.  Here are the different ways I added hours.

```
myCalender.add(Calender.HOUR,3)
```

and

```
myCalender.add(Calender.HOUR_OF_DAY,3)`
```

and

```
myCalender.setTimeInMillis( myCalender.getTimeInMillis() + (( (1000 * 60) * 60) * 3))`
```

If the begin date and time is for example `6/1/2011 11:00:00 PM GMT` and I execute the above code, I would expect the new date and time to be `6/2/2011 02:00:00 AM GMT` but what I got was `6/1/2011 02:00:00 AM GMT`. Can someone please educate me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
final DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
format.setTimeZone(DateUtils.UTC_TIME_ZONE);

final GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(DateUtils.UTC_TIME_ZONE);
cal.set(2011, Calendar.JUNE, 1, 23, 30, 0);
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Produces:

```
2011-06-01 23:30:00
2011-06-02 00:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the response to my question. Looking at your code I think my issues was with my local time zone.  You created a GregorianCalendar using UTC and when you displayed the date time you used a DateFormat that was also set to UTC. When I was looking at the date time, I was not setting the DateFormat to UTC so it was displaying the date time in my local time zone. My local time is less than UTC and therefore the previous day.  Makes more sense to me now thank you!

Comment: I suspected timezones, that's why I explicitly used UTC. Glad I could help, consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem.